# Windows Server 2008 Backup: When does it kick off a full backup?

Tags: windows-server-2008, backup, wbadmin

I was looking into the logs of my server 2008 jobs, and I notice that there are 2-3 days over the last month that WBADMIN has kicked off a full backup, rather than the incremental backups that it is supposed to do.

What criteria is WBADMIN looking for to kick off a full backup, even if we have the "always perform incremental backups" option checked?

Edit: Software that we are using is WBADMIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I would hazard a guess, and say that Incremental backups cannot be taken unless a consistent full is available, or at least the information of the lastest full is available. (to calculate which files to backup, etc).

When incremental jobs, run as full jobs, it's because this data is unavailable. I am only assuming that the backup program your using uses some sort of .... common sense!